# Draggable image on another Image IOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I Have been studying IOS and doing small apps that load Big Image to the app and there is a Small sticker image already in the app top of the loaded image that can drag around big image and place it anywhere.

First i have done by adding UIScrollView to the MainViewController and added imageView to that like below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
scrollView.delegate = self
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "demo")//Big Image
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.contentSize.height = 400
}
```

i have already placed small image top of that `UIScrollView`

but when i drag through top and bottom `Big Image` also scroll with `small image`. i want to drag only small image. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Moving a subview within a UIScrollView can be tricky because the gesture recognizer has to distinguish between a scroll drag and a subview drag.

Try add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the imageview and use its action method to capture the press. You can get the coordinates of the press in the image views space from the recognized gesture. Convert these to the super view's space, and set the position of the image view.